# Issue with synchronisation of Audience manager users

Tags: outbound-email

I have installed tridion audience manager

When i create an account on the website, it does indeed create the account in the audience manager, but when this user recieves a mailing, and the unsubscribe link is clicked, there is an issue with deleting the user in the audience manager.

**Core log of the presentation machine**

```
2013-05-03 15:58:50,544 ERROR Contact - Unable get contact for requested Identification fields
com.tridion.marketingsolution.profile.ContactDoesNotExistException: No contact record found for management side contact id: 17
 at com.tridion.marketingsolution.profile.Contact$1.execute(Contact.java:1481) ~[oe_profile.jar:na]
 at com.tridion.marketingsolution.profile.Contact$1.execute(Contact.java:1466) ~[oe_profile.jar:na]
```

When i look in the database, Tridion_cm_email Contacts table, i do see a user with ID 17. For some reason this user is not found.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When moving a user to an address book that isn't synchronized, the user disappears from the front-end database. This results in the database not being available anymore.

[image: Synchronize address book]